# Shopify Theme sectioin - blog posts - show only posts with specified tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm wondering what would be the best way to edit this theme section (blog-posts.liquid) to only show blog articles that are tagged with a specified tag. I've tried using this method (https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/limit-number-of-blog-posts-shown-with-a-specific-tag/td-p/1501546) but it would not work.

this is my blog-posts.liquid file.

```
{%- assign blog = section.settings.blog -%}

<section class="section" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="blog-posts">
  <div class="container">
    {%- if section.settings.title != blank -%}
      <header class="section__header">
        <h2 class="section__title heading h3">{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>

        {%- unless section.settings.link_title == blank -%}
          <a href="{{ blog.url }}" class="section__action-link link">{{ section.settings.link_title }} {% render 'icon', icon: 'tail-right' %}</a>
        {%- endunless -%}
      </header>
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- capture block_list -%}
      <div class="block-list block-list--loose">
        {%- for article in blog.articles limit: section.settings.blog_posts_count -%}
          <div class="block-list__item 1/2--tablet 1/3--lap-and-up {% if section.settings.stack_mobile and forloop.index == 3 %}hidden-tablet{% endif %}">
            {%- render 'article-item', article: article, featured: false -%}
          </div>
        {%- else -%}
          {%- for i in (1..section.settings.blog_posts_count) -%}
            <div class="block-list__item 1/2--tablet 1/3--lap-and-up {% if section.settings.stack_mobile and i == 3 %}hidden-tablet{% endif %}">
              <div class="article-item">
                <div class="article-item__image-container article-item__image-container--placeholder">
                  {%- capture placeholder -%}{% cycle 'lifestyle-1', 'lifestyle-2' %}{%- endcapture -%}
                  {{ placeholder | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                </div>

                {%- capture article_meta -%}
                  {%- if section.settings.show_category -%}
                    <span class="article-item__meta-item">{{ 'home_page.onboarding.article_category' | t }}</span>
                  {%- endif -%}

                  {%- if section.settings.show_author -%}
                    <span class="article-item__meta-item">{{ 'home_page.onboarding.article_author' | t }}</span>
                  {%- endif -%}

                  {%- if section.settings.show_date -%}
                    <time class="article-item__meta-item">{{ 'now' | date: format: 'short_month_day_year' }}</time>
                  {%- endif -%}
                {%- endcapture -%}

                {%- if article_meta != blank -%}
                  <div class="article-item__meta">
                    {{ article_meta }}
                  </div>
                {%- endif -%}

                <h3 class="article-item__title heading link h4">{{ 'home_page.onboarding.article_title' | t }}</h3>

                {%- if section.settings.show_excerpt -%}
                  <div class="article-item__excerpt rte">{{ 'home_page.onboarding.article_excerpt' | t }}</div>
                {%- endif -%}
              </div>
            </div>
          {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
      </div>
    {%- endcapture -%}

    {%- if section.settings.stack_mobile -%}
      {{ block_list }}
    {%- else -%}
      <div class="scroller">
        <div class="scroller__inner">
          {{ block_list }}
        </div>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</section>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Blog posts",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "blog",
      "id": "blog",
      "label": "Blog"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "blog_posts_count",
      "label": "Blog posts to show",
      "min": 3,
      "max": 9,
      "step": 3,
      "default": 3
      },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Blog posts"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "link_title",
      "label": "Link title",
      "default": "View all"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_category",
      "label": "Show category",
      "info": "The first article's tag will be shown as category.",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_author",
      "label": "Show author",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_date",
      "label": "Show date",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_excerpt",
      "label": "Show excerpt",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "stack_mobile",
      "label": "Stack on mobile",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "category": "Blog",
      "name": "Blog posts",
      "settings": {
        "blog": "news"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: where you tried the code suggested into the post?

Comment: @Onkar i Placed it below {%- for article in blog.articles limit: section.settings.blog_posts_count -%} - LINE 17

Comment: after placing the condition it show the results or not?